# How can I make collisions work properly in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I want to destroy enemies using unity collision system, must of the times works fine, the problem is when I have many enemies, around 30 on the screen. The projectiles just pass by some enemies.

I've tried changing variables on the RigidBody2D and the BoxCollider2D, those are set to kinematic and trigger with continuos collision but it seems that nothing is working

here is my code in c#

```
public void CheckForEnemyCollisionWithArrows(GridMap gridMap)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnedEnemies.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < projectiles.Count; j++)
        {
            if (
                    spawnedEnemies[i].boxCollider.IsTouching(projectiles[j].boxCollider) 
                    && !IntMask.Query(spawnedEnemies[i].flag, (int)EnemyFlags.IS_DYING)
               )
            {
                spawnedEnemies[i].SetEnemyFlag(EnemyFlags.WAS_HIT_TO_DEATH);
                projectiles[j].wasDestroyed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098572/where-to-attach-collision-detection-script) instead of rolling your own collision checking

Comment: I didn't want to use MonoBehaviour on every enemy that I add, but I guess that will be a quick solution, I'm adding a script just for collision detection. Thanks!, that solves the problem for now

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you want to, you can add your code below as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and get some reputation and help other people who come here with a similar question looking for help!